# Is there anyway to comunicate Simulink and Ros/Gazebo?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody:

I am using Ros Indigo, Gazebo2 and Linux 14.04.
I have a block diagram in Simulink that I would like to have in ROS/Gazebo to do simulations in 3D with this package https://github.com/RafBerkvens/ua_ros_p3dx .

Is there anyway to do that? and if there is not how can I do block diagrams with ROS.

Thanks you so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207114/is-there-anyway-to-comunicate-simulink-and-ros/gazebo?/) by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2015-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using Matlab 2015a, you should be able to use the *Robot Operating System Support* in the [Robotics System Toolbox](http://nl.mathworks.com/hardware-support/robot-operating-system.html). From that page:

> Create ROS nodes in MATLAB and Simulink, exchange messages with other nodes on the ROS network, import ROS log files into MATLAB, and generate C++ code for a standalone ROS node.

and

> You can develop, test, and verify your robotics algorithms and applications on ROS-enabled robots and robot simulators such as Gazebo and V-REP.

So with Gazebo on one side, Matlab on the other and ROS in the middle, you should be able to do what you described.

For other (older) versions of Matlab this should also be possible, but is a bit more involved.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0